# any working alternate to sketch.js for angualr2

Tags: angular

I am looking for any drawing framework for angaulr2 like sketch.js
tried using sketch.js with angualr2 but no luck.

is there any plugin or framework that I can use with angualr2 for drawing ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use many drawing libraries, since most of them aren't tied to specific SPA frameworks like angular. I used [ParerJS](http://paperjs.org) in my Angular 2 application and it works perfectly. However it took a while to figure out how to use it with Angular 2 (I ended up using npm version of this library with [Angular2-Webpack-Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter))

Comment: I came across paperJS but its not clear how I can create sketchpad from it. do you have any codepen or jsfiddle example. Thanx